# What is the maximum number of apps that can be transferred from one account to another in iTunes Connect:

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

How many apps can be transferred from one account to another in iTunes Connect? Are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There’s no limit to the number of apps you can transfer, but you need to transfer each app individually.

You can find the Apple documentation [here](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f)